# Changing the value of the parent by clicking a child in a expandable list view

Tags: android

Hi guys I am trying to change the value of the parent by clicking a child in a expandable list. I have looked for a solution but cant find anything.

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int              childPosition, long id){
            ExpandableListAdapter itemAdapter = parent.getExpandableListAdapter();
            String selectedItem = (String)itemAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            groupHeader(selectedItem);
            if(parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)){
                parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
            }

            return true;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

An ExpandableListView depends on an adapter to obtain its values.  Those values come from some sort of data structure, often an ArrayList or even a simple array.  In your onChildClick(), pass a reference to the data structure used to build your ExpandableListAdapter and modify the data structure directly, followed by a call to notifyDataSetChanged().

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
{
        ExpandableListAdapter itemAdapter = parent.getExpandableListAdapter();
        String selectedItem = (String)itemAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        groupHeader(selectedItem);
        if(parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
        {
            parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
        }
        // your logic here
        // expandableListArrayList.add() or expandableListArrayList.remove()
        // or whatever 
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }
});
```

You probably have to extend the adapter to create the functionality you need.  Your question is a bit nebulous because I can't see the overall structure of your code, but this should give you a running start.